# Convert Array to JSON string php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array like this

```
$prebook=array(
             'sourceCity'=>$_POST['source'], 
             'destinationCity'=>$_POST['dest'],
             'doj'=>$_POST['doj'],
             'routeScheduleId'=>$_POST['routeid'],
              'boardingPoint'=>array(
                  'id'=>$id,
                  'location'=>$location,
                  'time'=>$time
              ),     
              'customerName'=>$_POST['fname'],
              'customerLastName'=>$_POST['lname'],
              'customerEmail'=>$_POST['email'],
              'customerPhone'=>$_POST['mobileno'],
              'emergencyPhNumber'=>$_POST['emc-number'],
              'customerAddress'=>$_POST['address'],
              'blockSeatPaxDetails'=>array(array(
                  'age'=>$_POST['age'][$key],
                  'name'=>$value,
                  'seatNbr'=>$_POST['seat-no'][$key],
                  'Sex'=>$_POST['gender'.$no],
                  'fare'=>$_POST['base-fare'][$key],
                  'totalFareWithTaxes'=>$_POST['amount'][$key],
                  'ladiesSeat'=>$ladies,
                  'lastName'=>$_POST['plname'][$key],
                  'mobile'=>$_POST['mobileno'],
                  'title'=>'Mr',
                  'email'=>$_POST['email'],
                  'idType'=>$_POST['idtype'],
                  'idNumber'=>$_POST['id-number'],
                  'nameOnId'=>$value,
                  'primary'=>true,
                  'ac'=>$ac,
                  'sleeper'=>$sleeper
         )),
                'inventoryType'=>$_POST['invtype']             
           )
```

From this i want to get Json string look like this

```
apiBlockTicketRequest:{"sourceCity":"Hyderabad","destinationCity":"Bangalore","doj":"2016-01-22","routeScheduleId":"6717","boardingPoint":{"id":"2889","location":"Mettuguda,Opp. Mettuguda Church","time":"04:50PM"},"customerName":"jj","customerLastName":"jjj","customerEmail":"shamonsha665@gmail.com","customerPhone":"7779","emergencyPhNumber":"7878","customerAddress":"gjgj","blockSeatPaxDetails":[{"age":"22","name":"hjhj","seatNbr":"G4","Sex":"F","fare":"900","totalFareWithTaxes":"945","ladiesSeat":false,"lastName":"hjhj","mobile":"7779","title":"Mr","email":"shamonsha665@gmail.com","idType":"Aadhar Card","idNumber":"jkjk","nameOnId":"hjhj","primary":true,"ac":false,"sleeper":false}],"inventoryType":"0"}
```

Here is my code

```
$data =json_encode($prebook);
$json='apiBlockTicketRequest:'.$data;
echo $json;
```

But when i Validate the JSON string using [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) I will get the following error

> Expecting object or array, not string.[Code 1, Structure 1]
>
> Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: `$json='apiBlockTicketRequest'.$data;` That's why

Comment: Look  at the expected Json string

Comment: So that means you start making it by hand?

Comment: `$json='{apiBlockTicketRequest:'.$data.'}';` should be better. Even though writing your own JSON is generally a bad idea. Just let `json_encode` do all the work.

Comment: But Getting the same error

Comment: How to use `json_encode` to get the result as i expected?

Comment: @Rein even that is wrong. `apiBlockTicketRequest` should be quoted

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You creating invalid json by adding `apiBlockTicketRequest` to output

```
 $json='apiBlockTicketRequest'.$data;
```

instead you can do

```
$json = json_encode(['apiBlockTicketRequest' => $prebook]);
```

Comment: also if you have php < 5.4 then use `array()` instead of `[]`

Comment: But i don't want `{` at the begening and end of the string,bcz this json is  request of an api service,when i passw this json i wlll get an error from api,

Comment: Sorry but then don't use that service because it is asking you to produce ***invalid*** JSON

Comment: It is required to use { at the begginging so you asking about something that is *pseudo json* not JSON as @Hanky웃Panky mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct to make that `string` but the entire output string `($json)` will never parse as `json`, only the `$data` you encoded.